# References in function definitions and parameter definitions

Tags: php, reference

Heya, so I understand how the following should be used:

```
function test(&$obj) {
    {...}
}
```

But what does the following represent?

```
function &test(&$obj) {
    {...}
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This declaration:

```
function &test(&$obj)
```

Represents a function that takes in a reference to a variable as a parameter and returns a variable by reference.

Answer (score 1):

The function will return reference to the variable instead of the value.

See [Returning References](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.return.php) (PHP manual) for more information.

Comment: +1 for PHP manual link. For some strange reason none of my Google searches turned that page up.